# Shell script is failing with the error binary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am getting **cluster_network_operations.sh: line 44: [: 0: binary operator expected** error while runnign my script

In my script, I am calling the **ssh-copy-id** command and then based on its output I am setting the return code.

ssh-copy-id: output

```
WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.

Successful:

Number of key(s) added: 1

Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'bhupesh@10.236.61.133'", and check in:

2. All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system
```

I have used a function contains that checks for a substring in a string. Code snippet below,

```
contains() {
    # check if the substring exits in a string. 
    string="$1"
    substring="$2"
    if test "${string#*$substring}" != "$string"
    then
        return 0    # $substring is in $string
    else
        return 1    # $substring is not in $string
    fi
}

enable_auth(){
#   Enabling the authentication by sending the pub_key of all the nodes in
#   the cluster to the new gateway.
#   Currently, its a one way secure authentication.
    #pdsh -S -g all -N cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh "$2"@"$1" 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
    ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub "$2"@"$1"
    ret=$?
    #sub_str = "Now try logging into the machine, with"
    if [ contains "$ret" "Now try logging into the machine, with" ]
    then
        echo "Successfully Configured"
        ret=0
    elif [ contains "$ret" "All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system" ]
    then
        echo "System "$1" is already configured for the user: $2"
        ret=0
    else
        ret=1
    fi
    echo 0 
}
```

Comment: Remove `[` and `]` around call to `contains` function

Comment: $? is not ssh-copy-id output, but the return code, contains 0 "any string" has little meaning IMHO

Answer (score 0):

in shell return code 0 means success or true and <>0 means error

examples of usage of exit status

```
function contains {
    local string substring
    string=$1
    substring=$2
    [[ ${string#*$substring} != ${string} ]]
    return $?
}

if contains abc b; then echo ok; else echo KO; fi

if ! contains xyz c; then echo ok; else echo KO; fi

contains abc b && echo success
contains abc b || echo failed
```